# Include angularJS app in jquery app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, include, encapsulation

I have 2 applications, an angular app and a jquery app. I want to load my angular app with jQuery. This is my code (really simple) :

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <script>
       $("#div1").load("public/angular.html");//load angular app
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**public/angular.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/app.js">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**public/app.js**

```
angular.module("myApp", []);

angular.module("myApp").controller('AppController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Hi everyone !";
});
```

Is it posible to do it ? Is it a right way to do it ?

Thx for reply !

Comment: why not just use an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do angular bootstrap manually rather than ng-app
check Manual Initialization in [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Abdou, you're right ! That was the answer !

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <script>
        $("#div1").load("public/angular.html");//load angular app
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**public/angular.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      Hello {{greetMe}}!
    </div>

    <script>
      angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greetMe = 'World';
      }]);

      angular.element(document).ready(function() {
       angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```